# schema registry docker from confluent

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I want to use the schema registry docker (image owned by confluent) with my open-source Kafka I installed locally on my PC.

I am using the following command to run the image :

```
docker run -p 8081:8081  \
    -e  SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092 \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
```

but I am getting the following connection errors:

```
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Error while getting broker list.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:149)
    at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:150)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
[main] INFO io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Trying to query Kafka for metadata again ...
```

I have Kafka installed on my localhost.
Any idea to solve this, please?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 in Docker is almost always "this container", not the host.  (It is definitionally `localhost` and so there are multiple localhosts in this setup.)  You need to point at some other address where the Kafka broker can be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have Kafka installed on my localhost

As commented, localhost is unclear when you're actually using multiple machines (one physical and at least one virtual)

<strike>You need to use `host.docker.internal:9092`</strike>

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/ (removed because host is not windows)

On a Linux host, you need to use host networking mode

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Although, realistically, running Kafka in a container would be simpler for connecting the two

Comment: @cricket_007I am using linux I did this : SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=host.docker.internal:9092 and got new error : rg.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils - Couldn't resolve server host.docker.internal:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for host.docker.internal

Comment: Oh, by "PC" I assumed you meant windows.